# Vs code extension for bracket shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have just started js

is there any extension out there for vs code where we write e.g alert and it automatically puts () brackets infront of it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any extension, that puts the brackets after a function and there is a good reason.

Example:
If you want to pass a function to another function, your auto-brackets will execute your function and you just pass the return value.

```
function bar(value){
    return value + 1;
}

function foo(paramFunction){
    return paramFunction(3) + 3;   //will return 3+1+3 = 6
}

foo(bar)    //will pass the function bar as a parameter to foo
foo(bar(3))  //this will pass the return value of bar 4 to foo and will throw an exception
```

With such an extension the correct code is not possible.